# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_data/gc_content.txt'

Tags: python

I'm following a bioinformatics tutorial and have all the contents in a bioinformatics folder. Inside that, my python files are in one folder and txt files are in another. I receive the error in the title upon running it. I have already tried adding the parent folder to the readFile. It worked briefly and then stopped.

The instructor in the video has no issue using a relative path.

Bioinformatics

- rosalind_problems

  - stronghold

    - DNAToolkit.py
    - GC_content.py
    - structures.py
    - test.py
  - test_data

    - gc_content.tx

```
def readFile(filePath):
    '''Reading a file and returning a list of lines'''
    with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
        return [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]

def GCcontent(seq):
    #tmpFreqDict = {"A": 0, "C": 0, "G": 0, "T": 0}
    #for nuc in seq:
    #    tmpFreqDict[nuc] += 1
    #return tmpFreqDict["G"], tmpFreqDict["C"]
    return round((seq.count('C') + seq.count('G') / len(seq) * 100))

FASTAFile = readFile('test_data/gc_content.txt')
FASTADict = {}
FASTALabel = ""

print(FASTAFile)

# Converting FASTA file into a dictionary
for line in FASTAFile:
    if '>' in line:
        FASTALabel = line
        FASTADict[FASTALabel] = ""
    else:
        FASTADict[FASTALabel] += line
```

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Comment: Just updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Change `readFile('test_data/gc_content.txt')` with `readFile('../test_data/gc_content.txt')`